# Neighbor Joining Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, cluster-analysis

I am trying to implement a neighbor joining algorithm to create a phylogenetic tree. The algorithm is described here, which I have been using as a reference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_joining

I have gotten to the point where I need to start merging nodes, in the example they are merging a and b into u. I am having trouble with how to implement this in java. I have a distance matrix like this:

```
double[][] distanceMatrix = new double[][]{
    {0, 7,11,14},
    {7, 0,6,9},
    {11,6,0,7},
    {14,9,7,0}
};
```

I create a the Q matrix no problem, and identify the smallest value and therefore which nodes need to be merged. But when it comes to actually coding it, I'm stumped. I need to create a new similarity matrix with A and B replaced with U, so I assume I need to make a new matrix that's smaller than the one I started with, so I need to make a whole new matrix with size -1? I also need to keep track of the indexes, as they correspond to a specific sequences. Every time I merge they need to be shifted down, so I guess I would need some kind of list along side to keep track of where the sequences are going?

Can someone give me an idea of how to start?

Answer (score 0):

You can mark columns as "dead" if you don't want to rebuild your matrix.

Keep a list for each column with the aggregated (merged) contents.

Sounds much like the classic hierarchical agglomerative clustering (HAC) to me; there should be plenty of examples on how to implement this on a matrix.